# Is it possible to mimic or pass a file url to $_Files?

Tags: php

I need to modify an application that was custom built for us by someone else.
The application accepts a file (of type .ydk) from a form and then uploads that to WordPress (while also reading it's contents). I want to modify this so that it can also read a .ydk file from the server.

I've narrowed it down to the following:

```
if($_FILES['deckFile']){
    $attachment_ydk_id = upload_ydk_file($_FILES['deckFile']);
}
```

And the function it's  then using:

```
//Upload ydk file
function upload_ydk_file( $file = array() ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php' );
      $file_return = wp_handle_upload( $file, array('test_form' => false ) );
      if( isset( $file_return['error'] ) || isset( $file_return['upload_error_handler'] ) ) {
          return false;
      } else {
          $filename = $file_return['file'];
          $attachment = array(
              'post_mime_type' => $file_return['type'],
              'post_title' => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
              'post_content' => '',
              'post_status' => 'inherit',
              'guid' => $file_return['url']
          );
          $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file_return['url'] );
          require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
          $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $filename );
          wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $attachment_data );
          if( 0 < intval( $attachment_id ) ) {
            return $attachment_id;
          }
      }
      return false;
}
```

So the way I look at it. `$_Files` is needed since it's using `wp_handle_upload` which I believe requires `$_Files` array.

I tried `fopen` and `file()` as such but no luck:

```
    $attachment_ydk_id = upload_ydk_file(fopen("location_of_file.ydk", "r"));
```

**EDIT: 1st Attempt**

I've now tried the following (in an attempt to re-create $_Files):

```
$urls = 'YGOPRO_Decks/user_decks/58535.ydk';

$size = filesize($urls);
$info = pathinfo($urls);
$info_basename = $info['basename'];
$info_mime = 'application/octet-stream';

$UrlArray = array(
    'name' => $info_basename,
    'type' => $info_mime,
    'tmp_name' => 'YGOPRO_Decks/user_decks/58535.ydk',
    'error' => 0,
    'size' => $size
);  


if($_FILES['deckFile']){
    $attachment_ydk_id = upload_ydk_file($UrlArray);
}
```

The file exists in the location give. A `print_r` on the array gives:

```
 Array
(
    [name] => 58535.ydk
    [type] => application/octet-stream
    [tmp_name] => YGOPRO_Decks/user_decks/58535.ydk
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 576
)
```

Still no luck unfortunately. This seemed like a really good method and I thought I was on to something but it continues to fail.

Comment: `wp_handle_upload` calls `_wp_handle_upload`, and the latter uses `move_uploaded_file` internally to move the file to its target location; but that PHP function has a build-in check to verify the file originated from an actual file upload, for security reasons - if you try to move any other file that doesn’t fulfill this requirement, it will fail.

Comment: But the `pre_move_uploaded_file` filter allows you to interfere at this point - you’d need to handle moving of the yourself in your custom handler function, and then return `null` so that WordPress skips the part where it tries to move the file itself afterwards.

Comment: Why do you need to inject data into `$_FILES`? If the file is already on the server then just doing the `wp_insert_attachment` stuff should be enough?

Comment: @04FS You actually must return something different than `null` to make WP skip the attempt to move the file. [See line 848](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.2.3/src/wp-admin/includes/file.php#L848)

Comment: Try to read about `wp_handle_sideload`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation for [`wp_insert_attachement`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment), the file must be located in the uploads directory. Assuming you have access to the full WordPress library (since you are already calling into it), you can get the path using [`wp_upload_dir`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_dir/).

```
$tmp_file = wp_upload_dir() . '/' . basename($urls);
if (!copy($url, $tmp_file)) 
    exit();
```

Note: If you don't have WordPress loaded (e.g. if you are trying to run this as a script from the command line) then the `upload_ydk_file` isn't going to work as it relies on several WordPress functions.

You also aren't actually ever calling `upload_ydk_file` because you are still checking if the `deckFile` node of the `$_FILES` array is set before calling it.

```
if($_FILES['deckFile']){
    $attachment_ydk_id = upload_ydk_file($UrlArray);
}
```

If you remove that and always call `upload_ydk_file` since you know that $UrlArray will always be set then you should be good to go.

```
$urls = 'YGOPRO_Decks/user_decks/58535.ydk';
$tmp_file = wp_upload_dir() . '/' . basename($urls);
if (!copy($url, $tmp_file)) 
    exit();

$size = filesize($tmp_file);
$info = pathinfo($tmp_file);
$info_basename = $info['basename'];
$info_mime = 'application/octet-stream';

$UrlArray = array(
    'name' => $info_basename,
    'type' => $info_mime,
    'tmp_name' => $tmp_file,
    'error' => 0,
    'size' => $size
);  

$attachment_ydk_id = upload_ydk_file($UrlArray);
```

**EDIT:**
Using [`wp_handle_sideload`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_sideload) is a safer way to do move the file into the uploads directory. However, it is going to *move* the file, not copy the file so if you want to use that instead you should still copy the original file before passing that to `wp_handle_sideload`.

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right path by creating your own array for `$_FILES`. To continue on that, try adding the 'fake file' to the global like so:

```
$urls = 'YGOPRO_Decks/user_decks/58535.ydk';

$size = filesize($urls);
$info = pathinfo($urls);
$info_basename = $info['basename'];
$info_mime = 'application/octet-stream';

$UrlArray = array(
    'name' => $info_basename,
    'type' => $info_mime,
    'tmp_name' => 'YGOPRO_Decks/user_decks/58535.ydk',
    'error' => 0,
    'size' => $size
);  

$_FILES[$info_basename] = $UrlArray;

if(!empty($_FILES)) {
    $attachment_ydk_id = upload_ydk_file($UrlArray);
}
```

This should trick WP into thinking an actual file was uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Got around to finally implementing a solution for this. As a user kindly mentioned, `wp_handle_sideload` instead of `wp_handle_upload` was the solution. This allowed me to sideload a URL file alongside mimicing the `$_FILES` array.

```
//Upload ydk file
function upload_ydk_file( $file = array() ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php' );
      $file_return = wp_handle_sideload( $file, array('test_form' => false ) );
      if( isset( $file_return['error'] ) || isset( $file_return['upload_error_handler'] ) ) {
          return false;
      } else {
          $filename = $file_return['file'];
          $attachment = array(
              'post_mime_type' => $file_return['type'],
              'post_title' => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
              'post_content' => '',
              'post_status' => 'inherit',
              'guid' => $file_return['url']
          );
          $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file_return['url'] );
          require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
          $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $filename );
          wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $attachment_data );
          if( 0 < intval( $attachment_id ) ) {
            return $attachment_id;
          }
      }
      return false;
}
```

[wp_handle_sideload](https://hitchhackerguide.com/2011/02/12/wp_handle_sideload/)

> Handle sideloads, which is the process of retrieving a media item from
> another server instead of a traditional media upload. This process
> involves sanitizing the filename, checking extensions for mime type,
> and moving the file to the appropriate directory within the uploads
> directory.